# I can't create an object with my class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, ostream

I wanted to create a class that has all the features of ostream and some features added by me. The features added by me 
are missing because I haven't even started writing them and get an error :(

This is my sourcecode

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class my_ostream : ostream {};

int main() {
    my_ostream my_cout;    // my_cout is underlined
    my_cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

And here is the error i get

```
IntelliSense: the default constructor of "my_ostream" 
cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

I know what this means, but the default constructor should be accessable because there is one in ostream and it is inherited. So why can't I use it
because I think I should be able too...? :o

Thank you for reading <3 and helping me with this simple problem

Alex

Comment: C++ - Should that be `int main`?

Comment: Guess a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/ might be useful

Comment: The constructor does take a parameter

Comment: okay. But how can i make a filebuf when i want my_cout to do console output? And not like "text.txt" output

Comment: Do not inherit classes from `namespace std`, rule of thumb.

Comment: why not? I dont get it

Comment: If u dont want to help me just ignore it, this isnt helpful at all

Comment: Perhaps you should look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/ - but as @πάνταῥεῖ pointed out it is a bad idea to inherit as it leads to more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I want to do console output with my_ostream class, so ofstream won't help me

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The iostream classes were specifically designed to be inherited from.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda icky (possibly even really icky) but if you can tolerate having two output classes using the same output buffer, the OP is off to the races. If you want, you can steal cout's buffer and then point cout at another buffer to prevent cross pollution. That would probably lead to nasty surprises for people expecting good ol' cout to work, so it's probably worse that the buffer sharing.

```
#include <iostream>

class my_ostream: public std::ostream
{
public:
    my_ostream():std::ostream(std::cout.rdbuf())
    {

    }

    //extra functionality goes here
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    my_ostream my_cout;    // my_cout is underlined
    my_cout << "My Hello World!" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "cout Hello World!" <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D thats exactally what i wanted, I dont know but C++ is so complex xD

Comment: @Brogramer Bub, wait until you hit template metaprogramming.

Comment: I don't know if I will get so far... ;v